# Unable to find the Appendices of the Kate Polynomial Commitments paper

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, commitments

I am looking at the paper on [Kate Polynomial Commitments](https://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/techreports/2010/cacr2010-10.pdf).

The paper refers to Appendix A & Appendix B but it's not available with the document. Does anyone know where I find the full paper with the Appendices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be missing the obvious, but they seem to be in the PDF you linked, after the reference section. Appendix A starts at the bottom of page 18, appendix B halfway through page 19.

Comment: Oh, man. Sorry. I Control-F'ed for Appendix & didn't find any actual other title named Appendix A or Appendix B other than the lines referring to them  :-(